# HTML Email - Table Position

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, html-table

I have just started creating HTML emails. I am creating my latest one at 
http://www.jn-design.co.uk/misc/Swagelok/email.html

It displays fine in browsers , until IE, even 9 does not agree with it. I havent looked at the others yet. The correct display will be able to be seen within firefox or chrome.

Any ideas as to why half of the table has floated to the right?

Comment: I never try this. But look like a good start point: http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/#f1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting

```
<!doctype html>
```

at the top of your document, before the `<html>` tag

Comment: Thank you , I did not even think of this. Any ideas as to why my padding has been increased for all my elements?

Comment: It is normal, i had the same issue with ie and when i addedd the doctype declaration it increased padding, i think it happens because the doctype declaration puts the browser in standard mode for html-page display

Comment: Putting the doctype has increased my padding within all browsers?

Comment: Yes, it did increase your padding on all browser, it's normal, just put body{padding: _whatever_px} in your css and it should be ok

Answer (score 1):

You should add:
    align="center"
in place of:
    align="left"
on line 22.

I've done my fair share of HTML emails in my day!

Also add a doctype as well.

Comment: Any tips for my padding? Since putting in the doctype the padding within ALL browsers has greatly increased!

Answer (score 0):

For the paragraph padding, why don't you try setting the margins individually. I will also recommend [Boilerplate](http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/) since it contains a lot of solutions to the quirks of each email client.

Comment: Even when the paragraph padding is set to 0px in the body and the individual paragraph I need LESS padding , for some reason padding is being applied despite the heights not being that tall?....

Comment: You might have to ditch the `<p>` and just use `<tr>` and set the height/margins. Some clients will add extra padding to `<p>` that will override anything else.