# Outlook HTML Email

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-email

I have a HTML Email hosted at http://www.jn-design.co.uk/misc/Swagelok/email.html

The layout when being tested in earlier versions of outlook pre 2007 , seems to break. The content is moved to the right of the table and has cut off some of the bottom. If you view my link in your browser compared to the following screen shot you will see the problem. I previously had this problem within IE and solved it by re developing my email completely. Now the problem persists in Outlook...

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: How is this different from your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231669/html-email-table-position?

Comment: Because I had updated and re worked all of my template , as the last problem was in IE. I had then solved the problem in IE. Now though within Outlook the problem persists. Only outlook...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well my friend, I saw your code and it was breaking because you **had/have a lot of unclosed tags**

But to get your email to look good in Outlook you need to have a **container table of 100%**

I added this on fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/K8CLB/

As you can see making this.....

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  border="0"  align="center" bgcolor="white">
<tr>
<td align="center">
all your email here
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

.....will control the content ...by doing this I changed all your inner tables to be align center(and all 600)....there seems to be some other things you need to fix/close(you can do that...) but the centering is fixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou this has helped alot. Is there a reason why this is a solution to the problem?

Comment: you did have an overlay table...using this controls your email more...not having this can make outlook add to from their ourter layer shell they have.

Answer (score 1):

your main table has width=600, most of the inside tables have width=550, but those two "aberdeen.." and the next one have a width=600, change it back to 550 maybe it works

you forgot to close the table before the aberdeen table

also almost at the end you are not closing your

```
<a> tags (info@scotland..., and www.sagelok.com, and ESPN.Vatland....)
```

and there is maybe a closing

```
</td> and </tr> to much at the end, right before closing the last table!
```

Comment: use FireFox, press cmd+u (windows users should do with ctrl+u)!? and then you will see red highlighted if you do misstakes like this. also you could check your page at w3c and it will show you 26 errors mostly cleaning the first few cleans them all away

Answer (score 0):

Outlook really does screwy things with unvalidated HTML.

Please try: [W3C markup validation server](http://validator.w3.org/) to identify issues in your code. 
Also go to: [Campaign Monitor guide to CSS support in emails](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to find out whether your styling works across email clients. (and specifically in Outlook). There is a great blog resource there too.

Last comment, control width of items by declaring your widths in  tags. Example: width=400 (pixel based width) or width=100% (percentage based width -- beware because this may have problems in some clients)

A majority of normal styling is compatible if you code directly in  tags or in the  tag declaration. Don't try to style  tags because some clients strip this declaration from the email content. External css is also stripped in some clients.

tags can cause spacing issues in some browsers as well as  tags being overwritten by user-side style preferences. 
 and  are your friends.